# Method signature to cast void* to a pointer of specific type

Tags: c++, c++11, void-pointers, static-cast

Consider the following scenario:

```
enum Types { NONE, TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C }
struct TypeA { int i; double d; };
struct TypeB { int i; float f; };
struct TypeC { double d; };
```

All the `struct`s above are unrelated to each other.

Then there are several methods (of different signatures) that fill a `vector` of any of the `struct`s above as `void*`, for instance:

```
void GetTypeInstances (std:vector<void*>& typeInstances)
{
    void* inst;
    // some logic to create/fetch `struct` instances as void*
    typeInstances.push_back(inst);
}

void GetTypeInstancesAgain (std:vector<void*>& typeInstances, bool flag)
{
    void* inst;
    // some logic to create/fetch `struct` instances as void* using 'flag'
    typeInstances.push_back(inst);
}
```

In `main()`, I wish to do the following:

```
int main()
{
    std:vector<void*> typeInstances;
    GetTypeInstances(typeInstances); // fill the vector

    // depending upon the enum type I want to cast the members of the vector
    for (auto i = 0; i < typeInstances.size(); ++i)
    {
        switch(GetType()) // Types GetType(); is the signature
        {
        case TYPE_A:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeA*>(typeInstances[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        case TYPE_B:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeB*>(typeInstances[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        case TYPE_C:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeC*>(typeInstances[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Using another method to fetch the vector and access the instances
    std:vector<void*> typeInstancesAgain;
    GetTypeInstancesAgain (typeInstancesAgain, false); // fill the vector

    // depending upon the enum type I want to cast the members of the vector
    for (auto i = 0; i < typeInstancesAgain.size(); ++i)
    {
        switch(GetType()) // Types GetType(); is the signature
        {
        case TYPE_A:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeA*>(typeInstancesAgain[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        case TYPE_B:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeB*>(typeInstancesAgain[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        case TYPE_C:
            auto* inst = static_cast<TypeC*>(typeInstancesAgain[i]);
            // access 'inst' members
            break;
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------

    // Repeating the above for several other methods

    return 0;
}
```

Q1) Is there a way to extract the `switch` to a method that casts the `void*` to their respective types? I want to remove code duplicacy. Note that the `enum` contains many more types, and there are many more corresponding `struct`s for those types.

I am thinking of a method, but since the `struct`s have no relation among themselves, I am not sure how to go about solving this:

```
????  Cast(int enumType, void* ptr)
{
    ????
}
```

Q2) Will this problem be any simpler if the `vector` is filled with instances of a specific type only? If so, what would be it?

All possible leads are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to reinvent [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @john Sadly that's C++17. Any way to achieve it in C++11? Can a modified `tuple` be of any help?

Comment: I understand I can still use `boost::variant`, but what if I want to avoid that dependency altogether?

Comment: You'll still need code for all three types so I'm not sure what the advantage is...

Comment: @immibis What do you mean?

Comment: Ah, you mean if I make my vector as `std::vector<boost::variant<> >`, I'll still have to have the `switch` in `main()` to know what to `get()` from the `variant`. And this `switch` will be repeated several times? Yeah then this doesn't help!

Comment: You try to extract some homogeneous property from the structs so that you may treat them similarly, eg polymorphism

Comment: @PasserBy Even if I have, let's say, a `BaseType` as you suggested, I will still need to have the `switch` to `dynamic_cast` the `BaseType*` to the specific type. How does that solve my problem?

Comment: You get the structs to inherit from the base, and have virtual functions. Or even more explicitly, you assign a function pointer to each instance that does something specific for each type. That is what `std::variant`  does at its core

Comment: As discussed in the comments above, `variant` won't remove the duplicate code!

Comment: It does, it takes care of assignment/construction/destruction, for custom behavior use `std::visit`. Fetching the concrete object every time isn't how you're supposed to use it

Comment: But the use case is to access the data (getters/setters) of the concrete objects, not to do any operation on them (hence the use of `struct` with no *member functions*).

Comment: @CinCout I mean whatever you come up with you're gonna have to write `if(it's a TYPE_A) {access TYPE_A members} else if(it's a TYPE_B) {access TYPE_B members} else if(it's a TYPE_C) {access TYPE_C members}`. I don't see what you'd possibly do that you wouldn't have to write like that anyway - since they don't really have anything in common. You couldn't use `d` since TypeB is missing it, you couldn't use `i` since TypeC is missing it.

Comment: @immibis Exactly. Hence the question!

Comment: @CinCout What goes in the `// access 'inst' members` sections of the code?

Comment: @immibis I *get* `i`, `f`, or `d` to be used as the *key* of a `std::map`

Comment: @CinCout But how do you know which one to get?

Comment: Depends. But in most of the cases, it's the `i` that I want.

Comment: @immibis If all the `struct`s had an `int i`, and that is what I used as the *key* for `std::map`, would that help in solving the code-redundancy problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "// access 'inst' members" then you are more-or-less forced to write some code to do that in each case.

The obvious OO way round that would be to have a base class, and a pure virtual accesinstmembers() function, obviously named something more sensible.